# Include iscrollview.js with RequireJS and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs, iscroll

I'm slowly getting desperate on this one. I have a project where I use RequireJS to separate my JS code. I've managed to get this up and running, but now I'm having difficulties with the [iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) library. This provides an implementation of [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to use in jQuery Mobile websites. Here is some code to sketch my situation:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iscrollview</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/lib/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/lib/iscrollview/iscrollview.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main.js" src="js/lib/require/require-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-iscroll>
                    <!-- this contains some long content (long enough to trigger scrolling) -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h2>Footer</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min',
        jquerymobile: 'lib/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min',
        iscroll: 'lib/iscroll/iscroll',
        iscrollview: 'lib/iscrollview/iscrollview'
    },
    shim: {
        jquerymobile: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        iscroll: {
            deps: ['jquerymobile']
        },
        iscrollview: {
            deps: ['iscroll']
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery','jquerymobile','iscroll','iscrollview'], function($){

    /* I would expect that the correct JS files are loaded by the time we get here,
       so the iscrollview.js should recognize the data-trim attribute which I've applied
       earlier in index.html but unfortunately this doesn't happen in this implementation. /*

});
```

I hope I've pointed out my problem well enough for you guys to have a go out. Really appreciate the effort you put in to it!

**Edit:**

You can find the (simplified) project [here](https://rapidshare.com/files/470972654/iscrollview.zip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your .zip project I finally found the answer.
The iscrollview.js is self-initting, which you can see on line 1839 of the iscrollview.js file.
The self initialisation depends on the "pagecreate" event, which obviously already fired, when require.js loads in the file. 
**So the solution is to init iscrollview on our own**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min',
        jquerymobile: 'lib/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min',
        iscroll: 'lib/iscroll/iscroll',
        iscrollview: 'lib/iscrollview/iscrollview'
    },
    shim: {
        jquerymobile: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        iscroll: {
            deps: ['jquerymobile']
        },
        iscrollview: {
            deps: ['iscroll']
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery','iscroll','jquerymobile','iscrollview'], function($, iScroll){
    var elements = jQuery(document).find(":jqmData(iscroll)");
    elements.iscrollview();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to change much about the problem I'm having.

Comment: Okay could you provide a .zip file containing your project? I was just answering extemporaneously, but now I'd like to play with it a little more.

Comment: I added a download link to my original post.